# Como comparo un carácter en c++?

Tags: c++

Como comparar caracteres para identificar si son o no iguales, por ejemplo, yo de claro una variable `char carácter;` y luego unas líneas mas abajo de mi código digo la siguiente sentencia `cin>>carácter;` y luego digo

`while(caracter != 'A')...`

Esto me da error alguien sabe cual es la razón, me ayudaría muchísimo.

**EDITO**

El código real es:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char ingles;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  do {
    cout << "1. ingles tecnico: ";
    cin>>ingles;
  } while( ingles != 'a' || ingles != 'A');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola , podrías añadir el código completo , añadiendo también el mensaje de error que recibes.

Comment: ¿ `char carácter;` ? ¿ con tilde ? ¿ y luego `caracter != 'a'` ? ¿ **sin** tilde ?

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char ingles;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 
 do{
  
  cout<<"1. ingles tecnico: ";
  
  cin>>ingles;
  
 }while(ingles != 'a'  || ingles != 'A');
 
 return 0;
}

Comment: Si hubieras puesto el código **real**, te habrían respondido hace 2 horas :-/ Y, por favor, para próximas ocasiones, no uses los comentarios para añadir código. Usa la opción [*editar*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/61524/edit) que aparece *debajo* de la pregunta. Es la forma *mas mejor* de hacerlo :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que `while(ingles!='a' || ingles!='A')` siempre va a ser `true`, por lo que estarás en un bucle infinito.

Un carácter cualquiera **siempre** va a ser diferente a alguna de las dos opciones que pones.

Si quieres parar cuando se escriba A, sin importar si es mayúscula o minúscula:

```
do {
    ...
} while (ingles != 'a' && ingles != 'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

sube por favor el código, yo estoy usando CodeBlocks 16.01 y me funciona este algoritmo:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char d;
    do
    {
            cin>>d;
    }while(d!='A');
    return 0;
}
```